# Method that returns a Predicate < T > (where T is only known at runtime)

Tags: c#, generics, datagrid, filter, predicate

Im trying to apply a filter to a DataGrid in WPF and the filter property needs a Predicate

ex:

```
dataGrid1.Filter = p => p.A_Field_Table1.Contains(textBox.Text);
```

But my datagrid is being filled with reflection, so I only know the type of objects inside the datagrid at runtime.

Then I created a method that dynamically generates the Predicate< T > :

```
public static Predicate< T > GetPredicate< T >(string column, string valueP, T objSource, string table)
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);

        ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "p");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(predParam, itemType.GetProperty("A_" + column+ "_" + table));
        var valueStr= Expression.Constant(valueP);
        var typeOfStr = valueStr.Type;
        var containsMethod = typeOfStr.GetMethod("Contains", new [] { typeof(string) });
        var call = Expression.Call(left, containsMethod, valueStr);
        Func< T, bool > function = (Func< T, bool >)Expression.Lambda(call, new[] { predParam }).Compile();
        return new Predicate< T >(function);
    }
```

Then call this function on the interface:

```
var dataGridItem = dataGrid.Items[0];
dataGrid1.Filter = Class_X.GetPredicate(columnRefName,textBox.Text,dataGridItem,tableRefName);
```

But the generic method is throwing an exception saying that the type T is type of "object", even if objSource is type of Model.TableName.

I read some tutorials saying that T could not be resolved at runtime, then I should use "dynamic" instead of generic types.

I already tried using the "dynamic" type but I get a exception while casting the Lambda expression to Func< dynamic, bool>. Saying that I can't convert from < Model.TableName , bool > to < System.Object , bool >.

Is there an easier way to filter a datagrid that was filled by reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use generics in this case. `Filter` is a `Func<object, bool>`, so:

```
public static Predicate<object> GetPredicate(string column, string valueP, object objSource, string table)
{
    Type itemType = objSource.GetType();

    ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
    Expression left = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(predParam, itemType), "A_" + column+ "_" + table);
    var valueStr= Expression.Constant(valueP);
    var typeOfStr = valueStr.Type;
    var containsMethod = typeOfStr.GetMethod("Contains", new [] { typeof(string) });

    var call = Expression.Call(left, containsMethod, valueStr);

    //To handle null values. It considers null == string.Empty
    //var left2 = Expression.Coalesce(left, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));
    //var call = Expression.Call(left2, containsMethod, valueStr);

    //If you want null values to be distinct from string.Empty, it's
    //much more complex. You'll need a temporary variable (left2)
    //where to put the value of the property, and then you can use the 
    //Expression.Condition (that is the ? : ternary operator) to 
    //test for null values
    //var left2 = Expression.Variable(typeof(string));
    //var assign = Expression.Assign(left2, left);
    //var notNull = Expression.NotEqual(left2, Expression.Constant(null));
    //var call = Expression.Call(left2, containsMethod, valueStr);
    //var condition = Expression.Condition(notNull, call, Expression.Constant(false));
    //var block = Expression.Block(new[] { left2 }, new Expression[] { assign, condition });

    Predicate<object> function = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<object>>(call, new[] { predParam }).Compile();
    return function;
}
```

The "trick" is that in the returned function the parameter is casted to the "right" type (obtained by `objSource.GetType()`)

Be aware that you aren't testing for `null` values in the property of the row (`NullReferenceException` if you try to use `Contains` on a `null` property)

Comment: That's the problem, the type "T" is type object on the method call, but the objSource variable is type Model.Tablename... The type T could not be resolved at runtime so i cant create the lambda func (since it will use a column of the Model.Tablename to do the Contains("text") on the lambda)...

Comment: @RafaelA.M.S. Re-changed the code... Finally found which `Filter` you were using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter.aspx and it's a `Predicate<Object> Filter`

Comment: As you said, im not testing the null values in the properties of the row, and getting NullReferenceException when setting the filter... How to solve it?

Comment: @RafaelA.M.S. Add these two lines: `var left2 = Expression.Coalesce(left, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));
    var call = Expression.Call(left2, containsMethod, valueStr);`. They'll use the `??` coalesce operator and consider `null` to be `string.Empty`. If you want `null` to be "different" from `string.Empty` it's a little more difficult.